# About SSL session resumption: Two piece of material is inconsistent

Tags: ssl, openssl

Material A:
http://h71000.www7.hp.com/doc/83final/ba554_90007/ch04s03.html

Material B:
http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/5487?page=0,1

Here is a snapshot from material A that told me session resumption will be failed if I called SSL_free, even if save the session via SSL_get1_session().

[image: snapshot from Material A]

But a piece code in material B show me SSL_free will result in nothing for session resumption. Because SSL_get1_session will increase the reference counter in session object and allow SSL object to be reused after session freed.

Here is the snapshot from material B:
[image: snapshot from Material B]

So, those confused me so much, and which one is truly correct?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think source A is wrong and I think it mistakes SSL_get1_session with SSL_get_session, which actually is SSL_get0_session (does not increment the counter). The [OpenSSL documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_get_session.html) is clear in this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The [*man page*](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/SSL_free/) fully supports the second statement.